# Getting the insert ids in a MySQL Multi-Row Insert

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I am importing contacts from GMail, contacts can run into several hundreds and thousands.

I have this query doing the INSERT

```
$sql="INSERT IGNORE INTO lists (account_id, createdby, first_name, last_name, email, phone, date_created, list_type) VALUES $bindparam";
$importObj= otherquery($sql, $bind, $params);
```

I need to get the insert ids to enable me further insert their details in another table.

How do I go about this considering that I cannot run 1,000 queries or more in one import and also my auto-increment may not be consistent.
The application is also used by many people at the same time which may mean that more than two people may be running inserts at a time (Not only via import).

Comment: It looks like you have `email` in there - is that a unique key?  If so, use that to retrieve the id during subsequent `INSERT`s; theoretically, you don't need to pull the ids back at all....

Answer (score 0):

Yet another question right out of wrong assumptions.

> considering that I cannot run 1,000 queries or more in one import

Why such a consideration? Neither PHP nor mysql have no such a limit on the number of queries.

> also my auto-increment may not be consistent.

There are already hundreds of questions here from the same doubtful users, who never actually had any issue with auto-increment consistency, yet who worry of it just in advance. All with reassuring answers. Mysql developers are not *that* silly as you imagine. Nothing wrong will happen with your auto-increment.

I only hope that you are **queuing your import in some background process**, instead of making user to wait for it on-line. Having your import done this way, you should experience no problems with number of queries or script execution time or whatever. Just create a queue, either home-brewed one based on mysql table, or by using some dedicated software like RabbitMQ, and then make some of your backend servers to do all the import in background.